# About parabolic Kazhdan Lusztig polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, kazhdan-lusztig

There are two types of parabolic Kazhdan Lusztig polynomials, namely, of type -1: $P_{x,w}^{I,-1}$ and of type $q$: $P_{x,w}^{I,q}$. See [Kazhdan–Lusztig and R-Polynomials,
Young’s Lattice, and Dyck Partitions](https://msp.org/pjm/2002/207-2/pjm-v207-n2-p01-s.pdf)

My question: What is the meaning of $-1$ and $q$?

Comment: It woulod be helpful to refer to Deodhar's 1987 paper and Spergel's 1997 paper for the broader context.

Answer (score 6):

These polynomials are connected to the canonical basis of the induction from a parabolic subalgebra $H_I$ up to the whole Hecke algebra $H$. The difference is which module is being induced: The $q$-variant induces the trivial module (on which the generators $T_s$ of $H_I$ act as multiplication by $q$) while the $(-1)$ variant induces the sign module (on which the generators act as multiplication by $-1$).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: 1.I would like to how to induce from $H_I$ to $H$? 2. Is $H_I$ the Hecke algebra of Coxeter system $(W_I,I)$. 3. I would like to know is $H_I$-module, or the parabolic subalgebra $H_I$, or both being induced?

Answer (score 3):

these are polynomials in $q$ of two types, which satisfy either of the two recursions: 
$$P_{v,w}^{I,q}=-P_{v,ws}^{I,q}\;\;\text{or}\;\;P_{v,w}^{I,-1}=qP_{v,ws}^{I,-1},$$
see for example these [lecture notes.](https://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s72vortrag/Sentinelli.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your notes.

Comment: How did you prove the above recursions, do you have any references of the proof? I  cannot figure the proof out and doubt whether they are actually valid.